# URL Routing does not work on Windows EC2 instance

Tags: asp.net, web-config, url-routing

Recently we created a Windows Instance on Amazon EC2 and deployed our application.

Everything is working fine except URL Routing. For this I have googled everything and tried all the possible options right from changing the web.config, making sure HTTP Redirection feature is on in IIS and many other things but nothing seems to work it simply gives me 404 page not found.

My final web.config is looking like this beside the other required data

```
<system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />      
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<remove name="UrlRoutingModule"/>
<add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</modules>
<handlers>
<add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web,
Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>     
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>  
    </system.webServer>
```

Can I know what is that, which I am missing as I have tested out all the options and nothing is working.

Comment: Just a small update my application pool is running in Integrated pipeline and not classic.

Comment: Finally I was able to solve the error on my own. If anyone is facing a similar issue do not hesitate to contact me will be more than happy to assist you as I have wasted nearly 48 hours in solving this issue.

Comment: Hi, suddenly I'm facing the same problem. On other web sites it works, do you have some tips?

Comment: Hi where you able to solve your issue if not can you please elaborate so that I can be some help to you